# How can I save Chrome's opened pdf from ftp site?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ftp

I have opened a PDF file in Google chrome version 38 in Linux. But, when I wanted to save the PDF, Chrome wants to re-download again.

How do I save the pdf without re-downloading?

FYI, I could print the pdf. But I wanted to save the original copy. Is there  any way?

Comment: I have searched the cache, but it seems, the file is opened in the memory completely

Comment: No, usually when you open a file it is stored somewhere in the temporary internet files.

Comment: I'm in Linux and I thoroughly searched the directory. Nothing matched the size of the pdf.

Comment: I think @Anwar is right. This is probably why if you save the pdf, Chrome starts downloading again, unlike the case for a web link.

Comment: To avoid redownload, just use Print with "Save to pdf" option. I confirmed that with a pdf that is about 190MB. When I tried to save, the download started again, but print to pdf worked instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the mouse cursor to lower right corner and the "menu" with save icon appears.

Comment: Thanks, but, that was the first few things I did. I have tried several hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the pdf document opened in Chrome. A context menu should appear giving you the option to save the page/document.